# How to use "vuetify" transitions on my components?

Tags: javascript, components, material-design, vuetify.js

I'm using [Vuetifyjs library](https://vuetifyjs.com) in my project. I want to add transitions to my components - but there are no documentation about how to start transitions.

For example I want to add some transitions to appearance of my cards on screen.

```html
<v-card transition="v-slide-y-transition">
  <!-- content -->
</v-card>
```

How to start transition?

Answer (score 73):

This wraps some card text in a transition. When I trigger the v-show="show" model to true, the text slides in.

```
<v-slide-y-transition>
  <v-card-text v-show="show">
    Example text
  </v-card-text>
</v-slide-y-transition>
```

You could have a button trigger it or even add an onCreate() method that triggers the show to true after the component loads.

Comment: much-needed part of the documentation

Comment: Do you know if it also possible to trigger transitions when items appear/disappear due to classes like "hidden-xs-only"? I have  a component which disappears on small screens, but it would look much nicer if it would transition out of the view.

Comment: _Unknown custom element: <slide-x-transition> - did you register the component correctly?_

Comment: @gpasci You need to have the `v-` before the slide x transition, as in `<v-slide-x-transition>`.

Comment: Thanks you are right, the error was clear enough..I'll try again and report back

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use it with `v-for` (like with `<transition-group>`)?

Comment: How to add transition for disappearing the text?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Vuetify transitions around your router-view, the transition can sometimes be jarring on leave/enter.

To make the transition look smoother try the prop `hide-on-leave="true"`

```html
<v-scroll-x-transition mode="in" hide-on-leave="true">
  <router-view></router-view>
</v-scroll-x-transition>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```html
<v-fab-transition appear>
  <p>hello</p>
</v-fab-transition>
```